# PHP mailer not including body

Tags: php, phpmailer

i have the following form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input required="required" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" /><br /><br />
<input required="required" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /><br /><br />
<input required="required" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br /><br />
<input required="required" name="website" type="text" placeholder="URL to blog / website" /><br /><br />
<input type="file" name="file" /><br /><br />
<textarea name="message" cols="" rows="10" placeholder="Message (optional)"></textarea><br /><br />
<input name="send_form" type="submit" value="Submit" style="float:right; width:200px;" />
</form>
```

And this is my php:

```
$mail             = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "xxxxxx"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Username   = "xxxxxxx";// SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "xxxx";        // SMTP account password
$mail->From = $_REQUEST['email'];
$mail->FromName = $_REQUEST['name'];    
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = "CV Upload";

$body = 'Name:'.$_REQUEST['name'].'<br /><br />Email:'.$_REQUEST['email'].'<br /><br />Email:'.$_REQUEST['website'].'<br /><br />Message:'.$_REQUEST['message'].'<br /><br />'; 

$mail->Body    = $body;
$mail->AltBody = $text_body;
$mail->AddAddress("danyob@rbh.co.uk");
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
if($mail->Send()){
    $success = true;        
}else{
    $success = false;
}//if($mail->Send()){}
```

For some reason the body of the content is not showing in the email i receive. Subject line and everything else works. Anything wrong with the above?

Comment: Where do you declare $body and $text_body? I only see a text area named 'message'.

Comment: $body is basically all form fields, as stated above.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, didn't noticed that.

Comment: If you echo $body, before sending it, does it give you the correct result?

Comment: i have just tested this, nothing is returned?

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the result of `$mail->Body` before you do `$mail->Send()` and check your mail with **HTML enabled** mail client. Observe that `$mail->AltBody` is filled with contents of `$text_body` variable which is not defined in the code you presented. It may be empty and if you're using text-only mail client, you'll see no text at all. You may try to do simple test and try those lines of code to see which content is visible in your mail client:

```
$mail->Body    = '<h1>HTML</h1>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Plain text';
```